# What is nautilus doing?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, hud

Lately my Ubuntu 14.04 computer has been quite noisy. It's the CPU heat sink that's unusually active. If I run `top`, I see that `hud-service` is taking up ever more memory (59% of 8GB at this moment), with 101% of CPU being used by it. I killed this process, and the heat-sink fan is less constant, but still going more often than it should. Looking at top now, I see that Nautilus is taking about 38% of the CPU up. It has been doing this for days now.

Why!? What could Nautilus possibly be doing?

Comment: You can check with "top" or "htop"

Comment: OK htop gives me nautilus --new-window at 37% CPU. Any idea what this is doing and why?

Comment: Since restarting, hud-service is back, and it's eating up more and more RAM by the hour (17% of 8GB). Why is this?

Comment: OK, if it helps anyone, it appears to have been related to a very very large image file I had on my desktop. My guess is that nautilus was trying to create a thumbnail and never managed for reasons relating to its size. Anyway, I deleted it, and the cpu-fan went quiet.

Comment: ah! check nautilus settings; you can limit the size on when it should make those! nice find! and please if you read this: post is as an answer please!

Answer (score 3):

It appears to have been related to a very very large image file I had on my desktop. My guess is that nautilus was trying to create a thumbnail and never managed for reasons relating to its size. Anyway, I deleted it, and the cpu-fan quietened down.